# Gnuplot - "zoom in" part of x-axis

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

I have a data row with lots of dots, plotted as markers. X-axis values range between 0 and 80 ms, and Y-values take discrete values of 1,2,..5. There are about 50000 points, so if I just plot them as usual, the Y-value changing dynamics is not clear, as you see for example a solid line forming at Y value 5, with a few dropouts at 3 and 4. I would like to modify my plot to zoom in the first millisecond - the half of the X-axis should be occupied by the range 0-1ms, and the rest 1-80ms. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I guess, the best way would be to have two plots beneath each other (use `set multiplot layout 1,2`). That way the different scalings become more obvious. Or do you really want a single plot with the different scalings?

Comment: Consider a [broken axis](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.fr/2010/06/broken-axis-once-more.html) (in your case the x-axis and not the y-axis). And as Christoph said, it'll be a `multiplot` solution.

Comment: You can find a more detailed [broken axis](www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/) example from the same author on his/her older page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
set yrange [-1:1.3]
set xrange [0:12]
set x2range [40:150]
set xtics 0,1,5
set x2tics 100,10,150 mirror offset 0,-21.6
plot (x<5?sin(x):0/0) axis x1y1 tit "f(x)", (x>100?cos(x):0/0) axis x2y1 tit "g(x)"
```

Constant `-21.6` is setting up xtics labels for second part but according to `x2` (upper) axis... So you must fit this constant according to graph height and used terminal. Also you have to change range and tics settings to obtain continuous x axis.

Comment: So you wll need: set xrange [0:2]; set x2range [-78:80] #one is in the center. set xtics 0,.2,1; set x2tics 10,20,90 Or sth. similar.